# Using Spark DataFrame directly in Keras (databricks)

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, keras, pyspark, databricks

I have some text that I am looking to classify with keras.  I have created a pipeline that takes the text and does some transformations on it and eventually one hot encodes it.

Now, I want to pass that OneHotEncoded column directly into keras in databricks along with the label column, but I cannot seem to do it.  All of the examples that I see seem to start with a pandas dataframe and then convert to to a numpy array.  But it seems counterproductive to take my pyspark dataframe and convert it.

```
model.fit(trainingData.select('featuresFirst'), trainingData.select('label'))
```

gives me:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'values'


model.fit(trainingData.select('featuresFirst').collect(), trainingData.select('label').collect())
```

gives me:

```
AttributeError: ndim
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Bah, yeah i have several TB of data that i don't want to save to S3